# How to disable future dates after a week in input type = date?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `input` box of `type=date`. I want it to disable all dates after one week from current date. Suppose current date is 11/07/2017, I want all dates from 18/07/2017 to be disabled. So the user can select only dates within one week from today. I've already disabled the past dates in my code.

```js
function validDate(){
    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
}
```

```html
<body onload="validDate()">
  <div class="form-group">
     <p>Date<span>*</span></p>
     <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control input-sm " required />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You would have to add 7 days to `today` then change the `min` to `max`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the updated code.

```
[after how many number of days to be disabled i.e. 6 in this case] * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

`min` and `max` attributes are used to set the minimum and maximum date for type="date"

```js
function validDate(){
     var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
     var nextWeekDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split('T')[0]
      document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
      document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('max', nextWeekDate)
 }
```

```html
<body onload="validDate()">
<div class="form-group">
            <p>Date<span>*</span></p>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control input-sm " required />
          </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'max' to disable the future date:

```
var nextWeek = new Date();
nextWeek = nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 1).toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('max', nextWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like

HTML

```
<table width="68%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6">

      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="search-filter-headings">Start Date:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="filter-textfields" placeholder="Start Date"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="search-filter-headings">End Date:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="filter-textfields" placeholder="End Date"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $( "#start_date" ).datepicker(

        { 
            maxDate: '0', 
            beforeShow : function()
            {
                jQuery( this ).datepicker({  maxDate: 0 });
            },
            altFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

        }

);

$( "#end_date" ).datepicker( 

        {
            maxDate: '7', 
            beforeShow : function()
            {
                jQuery( this ).datepicker('option','minDate', jQuery('#start_date').val() );
            } , 
            altFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

        }

);
```

Working Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/544/

Let me know if you require any further help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-max) attribute of the date picker.

```js
function getInputDateFormat(date) {
  return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

function validDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 7);

  document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', getInputDateFormat(today));
  document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('max', getInputDateFormat(maxDate));
}
```

```html
<body onload="validDate()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Date<span>*</span></p>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control input-sm " required />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the `max` attribute for the date:

```
function validDate(){
    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    var newDate = today()today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
    document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
    document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('max', newDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use php date to pass min and max parameter in input date check below code

```
<input type="date" name="date" min="<?=date('Y-m-d')?>" max="<?=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date('Y-m-d').'+7 days'))?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

to add to @lalit sachdeva's code

I wanted where someone can only select 3 days from today and a max of 10 days from then. So here is the edited code if someone needs + 72 hours and max 10 days.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var today = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        var nextWeekDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().split('T')[0]
      document.getElementsByName("merchant_param3")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
      document.getElementsByName("merchant_param3")[0].setAttribute('max', nextWeekDate);
});
```